# Wp7:Push notification channel URI is null

Tags: windows-phone-7, push-notification, mpns

We are trying to test push notifications, using the latest code from the documentation How to: Set Up a Notification Channel for Windows Phone

```
public HttpNotificationChannel myChannel;
public void CreatingANotificationChannel()
{
  myChannel = HttpNotificationChannel.Find("MyChannel");

  if (myChannel == null)
  {
    myChannel = new HttpNotificationChannel("MyChannel","www.contoso.com");

    // An application is expected to send its notification channel URI to its corresponding web service each time it launches.
    // The notification channel URI is not guaranteed to be the same as the last time the application ran.
    myChannel.ChannelUriUpdated += new EventHandler<NotificationChannelUriEventArgs>(myChannel_ChannelUriUpdated);

    myChannel.Open();
  }
  else // Found an existing notification channel.
  {
    // The URI that the application sends to its web service.
    Debug.WriteLine("Notification channel URI:" + myChannel.ChannelUri.ToString());
  }

  myChannel.HttpNotificationReceived += new EventHandler<HttpNotificationEventArgs>(myChannel_HttpNotificationReceived);
  myChannel.ShellToastNotificationReceived += new EventHandler<NotificationEventArgs>(myChannel_ShellToastNotificationReceived);
  myChannel.ErrorOccurred += new EventHandler<NotificationChannelErrorEventArgs>(myChannel_ErrorOccurred);
}
```

If HttpNotificationChannel.Find() returns null, it opens a new channel, but the ChannelUriUpdated event is never triggered.

If HttpNotificationChannel.Find() returns a channel, the ChannelUri property is null.  The sample code crashes here because it assumes the ChannelUri property to be not null.

In neither case is the ErrorOccurred event triggered.

How can i solve this problem? This problem is because of microsoft server or any thing else?

Thnks in advance

**EDIT**
Waiting for replay,after ten days i am suffering of null uri problem
Can any one tell me how can i solve this problem some time MSPN server give chanalk uri ans some time not i mean some time it give null reference Exception. 
What  Microsoft doing?

Answer (score 1):

If I don't go wrong, www.contoso.com it's a example URI to demonstrate that you need to put your own server URL address, but in my experience, I never use in that way. I prefer just to put

```
myChannel = new HttpNotificationChannel("MyChannel");
```

Look this [example](http://blogs.ligasilverlight.com/2011/06/notificaciones-de-empuje-para-el-desarrollo-de-windows-phone/) (it's in Spanish) but the codes are very clear of what you need to do to set the push notification client and service.

I hope I helped you.

Comment: thnanks for replay and i am using same like this myChannel = new HttpNotificationChannel("MyChannel"); but not working some time uri fire null reffrence exception

Answer (score 0):

You are testing in what mobile are Emulator,
Do you have developer account subscription for windows phone development,
Had you Developer unlocked your mobile,

Noorul.

Comment: :i am testing this demo with mobile and yes i have developer account and also yes for Had you Developer unlocked your mobile,

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem is that you are using the `HttpNotificationChannel` constructor of the authenticated web service, according to the [documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/ff403009%28v=vs.105%29.aspx).

Instead, you should use the constructor that takes only one parameter, as you can check in [this example](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/hh202967(v=vs.105).aspx)

```cs
/// Holds the push channel that is created or found.
HttpNotificationChannel pushChannel;

// The name of our push channel.
string channelName = "ToastSampleChannel";

// Try to find the push channel.
pushChannel = HttpNotificationChannel.Find(channelName);

// If the channel was not found, then create a new connection to the push service.
if (pushChannel == null)
{
    pushChannel = new HttpNotificationChannel(channelName);
    ...
}
```

Hope it helps